# Error con phpmailer

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, phpmailer

Estoy haciendo una web institucional, creando el formulario de contacto para poder envíar consultas al mail de gmail. Los mensajes llegan perfectamente, pero cuando lo envío me aparece esta imagen, justo debajo del formulario.

```js
<?php

$nombre= $_POST['name'];
$email= $_POST['email'];
$asunto= $_POST['subject'];
$mensaje= $_POST['message'];

$body = "Nombre: ". $nombre ."<br>Correo: ". $email . "<br>Asunto ". $asunto . "<br>Mensaje: " . $mensaje;


use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

require 'phpmailer/Exception.php';
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailer.php';
require 'phpmailer/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);




try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                              // Send using SMTP
 $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'prueba@gmail.com';                     // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = 'clave';                               // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('tucorreo@correo.com', 'Envio');
    $mail->addAddress('prueba@gmail.com',$nombre);     
    

    

    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = $asunto;
    $mail->Body    = $body;
    $mail->AltBody = 'Hay un correo desde el sitio web';

    $mail->send();
    echo '<script>
    alert("Consulta enviada")
    </script>';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Revisa  la documentación de PHPMailer para desactivar el debug aquí: `$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eso es porque tienes activado el debug. Es la primera línea.

```
 $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      // Enable verbose debug output
```

Deberías cambiar eso a

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
```

Comment: Ahí se desactivo el mensaje lo único es que me sigue apareciendo el recuadro rojo , en la documentación dice que el valor tiene que ser SMTP::DEBUG_OFF;

Comment: Si lees la documentación, https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/SMTP-Debugging dice que DEBUG_OFF es realmente un cero. Igualmente ambas cosas deben funcionar porque es un alias.

Hay que ver qué genera el recuadro rojo. PHPMailer no da formato html a sus salidas. Quizás viendo todo el código se te pueda ayudar en eso.